# git: disable automatic pushing to a certain remote branch

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote

When I run `git push`, my local branch `some_branch` is pushed to a remote branch `some_remote\some_branch`.

When I run `git remote show some_remote` I get:

```
Local refs configured for 'git push':
[cut]
some_branch         pushes to some_branch
```

I don't want this. How do I remove this entry?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest answer is to rename your local branch some_branch to another name, e.g. with:

```
git branch -m some_branch a_branch_name_not_present_on_some_remote
```

The reason for this is that `git push` by default pushes each branch to a branch with a matching name on the remote, if such a branch exists there.  If you don't like this behaviour in general, you have to change the [push.default](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_variables) config option.  For example, you could do:

```
git config --global push.default tracking
git branch --set-upstream some_branch origin/totally_different_branch
```

I wrote a bit more [here](http://longair.net/blog/2011/02/27/an-asymmetry-between-git-pull-and-git-push/) about the behaviour of `git push` where you don't specify the refspec explicitly.

Comment: Thanks :) I've gone with the config.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way - edit it out of your .git/config file.

Comment: But is there a way to pull from a remote branch but not push to it?

Comment: @mathick - yes, by not using push pull/pull. Run `git remote update` which will pull down all the remote changes, and then you get run `git merge origin/<branchname>` manually to get the current changes from <branchname>

Comment: But how do you push the changes to the remote? Maybe you mean you have a "pull only" model in mind?

Comment: @mathtick You asked how to pull but not push, so why are you now asking how to push?

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear: how to push/pull asymetrically across branches (i.e. have some branches as "pull-only" in a certain repo). I'm probably not using git right by asking these questions anyway :)