# How to configure git put push only some branches and ignore others?

Tags: git, git-push

I want to prevent some git private branches from being pushed upstream.

How can I achieve this?

Any of the folowing kind of solutions would be acceptable:

- push only branches in a list
- skip pushing branches in a list

Update: currently my push configuration is using `mirror=true`, which means that will push all branches.

Explanation, we do have an internal centralized repository inside the company which is mirrored to github. We do want to get all braches to the company-repository, which is already happening but I do want to be able to limit what goes to public to github, so not all branches will go public.

The problem is that now everything goes to github, probably due to the mirror option. If I remove it it will probably push only the branches that do already exists on github.

Still, even this option is not what I want, as I want to be able to control which ones are to be skipped or included.

If this can be done using a regex pattern, the better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git: disable automatic pushing to a certain remote branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083564/git-disable-automatic-pushing-to-a-certain-remote-branch)

Comment: Udpated the answer, it is not a duplicate of the existing question.

Answer (score 2):

Set push policy to upstream:

```
git config --global push.default=upstream
```

(If you just want it for a single repo and not for all repos on your machine, skip the `--global` part)

Then, make sure the private branches have no upstream branch set (that would probably be the case if you haven't set it up manually)

```
git branch -vv
```

If there are any remote tracking branches, remove them with:

```
git branch -d -r origin/<remote branch name>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that my current configuration is using the mirror=true option.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to decide whether you really want to mirror or not. If you really want to mirror, then all refs will be pushed by an unadorned `git push` or `git push <remote>`. You can still do `git push <remote> <localbranch>:<remotebranch>`, but if you want to push a bunch of branches that can get tedious unless you script it, and even then, if the set of branches you want to push changes often, it can still be a pain.

Probably your better option is to turn mirroring off, and explicitly set up in `.git/config` the branches that you do want to push, as well as a suitable default mode for when you do a `git push` without specifying branches. pgilmon's answer gives one possible setting for that default - read the documentation to decide if that's the most useful default mode for you (newer versions of `git` offer more different modes for that default, as well as implementing a different "default default" if you don't specify one).